# Cronjob php file with curl in it works in browser but at crontab it works wrong

Tags: php, mysql, curl, cron

i have a file `cron.php` in it is a `CURL` function.
The `CURL` function writes content from a diferent website in my database.
If i call it in the browser it works fine, but in the cron jobs it write the wronge content from the site into my database.

Is there a problem between `crontab` and `CURL` in php files?

#### UPDATE

the curl function:

```
function CurlPost($sURL,$sMessage = "")
{

    $cookie_file_path = "cookies/cookies.txt";
    print_r($sMessage);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sMessage);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


    $sResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $sResult;


}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the data that should be written and the data that is written on both development and production server.

Comment: Could you provide some code from the cron.php as an example?

Comment: fixed it thanks all for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to provide full/absolute path for file name when running it from cron. You must be using  cookie with your curl, and that is lacking of absolute path. Hence the cookie is not working and you are getting wrong content.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

So `cookie.txt` should be `/home/tmp/cookie.txt`